# Pandas: read_csv ignore rows after a blank line

Tags: python, pandas

There is a weird .csv file, something like:

```
header1,header2,header3
val11,val12,val13
val21,val22,val23
val31,val32,val33
```

pretty fine, but after these lines, there is always a blank line followed by lots of useless lines. The whole stuff is something line:

---

```
header1,header2,header3
val11,val12,val13
val21,val22,val23
val31,val32,val33

dhjsakfjkldsa
fasdfggfhjhgsdfgds
gsdgffsdgfdgsdfgs
gsdfdgsg
```

---

The number of lines in the bottom is totally random, the only remark is the empty line before them.

Pandas has a parameter "skipfooter" for ignoring a known number of rows in the footer.

Any idea about how to ignore this rows without actually opening (open()...) the file and removing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `csv` module, it's fairly trivial to detect an empty row.

```
import csv 

with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for l in r:
        if not l:
            break
        #Otherwise, process data
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, that's my point, I was wondering whether is it possible to combine pandas parameters only, without actually opening the file. Thank you.

Comment: @ThiagoMelo it looks like `read_csv` accepts text buffers, so you could have a function that just writes the data across that way and prints EOF to the buffer when it sees an empty line.

Answer (score 5):

There is not any option to terminate `read_csv` function by getting the first blank line. This module isn't capable of accepting/rejecting lines based on desired conditions. It only can ignore blank lines (optional) or rows which disobey the formed shape of data (rows with more separators).

You can normalize the data by the below approaches (without parsing file - pure `pandas`):

1. Knowing the number of the desired\trash data rows. [Manual]

   `pd.read_csv('file.csv', nrows=3)` or `pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipfooter=4)`
2. Preserving the desired data by eliminating others in `DataFrame`. [Automatic]

   `df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', inplace=True)`

The results will be:

```
  header1 header2 header3
0   val11   val12   val13
1   val21   val22   val23
2   val31   val32   val33
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution:**

```
df = pd.read_csv(<filepath>, skip_blank_lines=False)
blank_df = df.loc[df.isnull().all(1)]
if len(blank_df) > 0:
    first_blank_index = blank_df.index[0]
    df = df[:first_blank_index]
```

**Explanation:**

The best way to do this using pandas native functions is a combination of arguments and function calls - a bit messy, but definitely possible!

First, call `read_csv` with the `skip_blank_lines=False`, since the default is `True`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(<filepath>, skip_blank_lines=False)
```

Then, create a dataframe that *only contains* the blank rows, using the `isnull` or `isna` method. This works by *locating* (`.loc`) the indices where all values are null/blank.

```
blank_df = df.loc[df.isnull().all(1)]
```

By utilizing the fact that this dataframe preserves the original indices, you can get the index of the first blank row.

Because this uses indexing, you will also want to check that there actually is a blank line in the csv. And finally, you simply *slice* the original dataframe in order to remove the unwanted lines.

```
if len(blank_df) > 0:
    first_blank_index = blank_df.index[0]
    df = df[:first_blank_index]
```