# Stop reading the CSV file after finding empty rows python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file that has four parts that are on the same page but distinguished by putting some empty rows in the middle of the spreadsheet. I want to somehow ask pandas to stop reading the rest of the file as soon as it finds the empty row.

Edit: I need to elaborate on the problem. I have a CSV file, that has 4 different sections that separated with 3-4 empty rows. I need to extract each of these sections or at least the first section. In other words, I want read_csv stop when it finds the first empty row(of course after skipping rows with detail about the file)

```
url = urlopen("https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/30_Industry_Portfolios_CSV.zip")

zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(url.read()))
data = pd.read_csv(zipfile.open('30_Industry_Portfolios.CSV'), 
                     header = 0, index_col=0,
                     skiprows=11,parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: read\_csv ignore rows after a blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045510/pandas-read-csv-ignore-rows-after-a-blank-line)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator.

Suppose the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is generating rows.
(We might use `yield from sheet`,
except that we'll change the loop in a moment.)

```
import csv

def get_rows(csv_fspec, skip_rows=12):
    with open(csv_fspec) as fin:
        sheet = csv.reader(fin)
        for _ in range(skip_rows):
            next(sheet)  # discard initial rows
        for row in sheet:
            yield row

df = pd.DataFrame(get_rows(my_csv))
```

Now you want to ignore rows after encountering some condition,
perhaps after initial column is empty.
Ok, that's simple enough, just change the loop body:

```
        for row in sheet:
            if row[0]:
                yield row
            else:
                break  # Ignore rest of input file.
```